# Xcode / iOS / When I make 'insertSubview' it's not change orientation, how fix?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I create UIView like this:

```
UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
//Make some things with someView
[self.view.superview inserSubview:someView belowSubview:self.view];
```

When I rotate device - self.view change orientation, but someView in the background - not. What I miss?

Comment: you're either not applying any `Autolayout` constraint or missing `Autosizing` masks on `someView`. If you have neither and only a frame invloved then you'll have to manually change it's frame in `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:`. But i'll strongly recommend you go via `Autolayout` or atleast `Autosizing`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someView is not part of the view controller that handles the device rotation. 
you can try this:

```
UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:someView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:someView]
```

Comment: Maybe you know how to set Auto-layout correctly? To change width/height equal screen after rotation. I try 'addConstraintsWithItem' to 'someView', but it's not work, writes an error...